# Contador en SQL server

Tags: sql, contador, server

quería consultarles sobre este error al contar registros.
Esta es la consulta:

```
SELECT COUNT(A.PTA, B.ORD)

FROM 

CLIESO A , 

CLIORD B

WHERE  A.PTA = B.PTA 

AND A.ORD = B.ORD

AND A.EST = 'PCRCOR'

AND B.FEC_ATE 

BETWEEN (SELECT  DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEADD(day , 1 , EOMONTH(GETDATE()))))

AND (SELECT EOMONTH(GETDATE()))
```

y este es el error:

> Mens. 8120, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 1 Column 'CLIESO.PTA' is invalid
> in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate
> function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: ¿Que buscas con `SELECT COUNT(A.PTA, B.ORD)`? ¿no debería ser en todo caso `SELECT COUNT(A.PTA), COUNT(B.ORD)`?

Comment: Esa consulta no puede generar ese error. Va a generar otros, pero ese no.